# Implementing a script from Drupal VoIP in hook_cron

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, voip, cron-task

I have a voip script located below

```
    $call= new VoipCall();
    $phone_number='phone_number';
    $text="example text"
    $script= new VoipScript('example');
    $call->setScript($script);
    $success=voip_text($text, $call);
```

Which I am trying to call within a method which implements hook_cron(). However, when I try to call/ text, I receive the error:  *User 0 does not have permissions to make outbound calls or texts.*  I was wondering if anyone had any idea why this error occurred and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a matter setting the appropriate permissions. In Drupal 7, go to /admin/people/permissions and enable "make outbound calls" for anonymous users. Hope that helps!